# Lazy initialization fetching failed in spring boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have these Entities in spring boot as bellow

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    long id;
    String recipient;
    String sender;
    String issueDate;
    boolean isApproved;
    String status;
    String blockchainTx;
    String UUID;
    boolean miningStatus;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createDateTime;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    Users user;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice")
    List<Item> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    public Invoice() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getIssueDate() {
        return issueDate;
    }

    public void setIssueDate(String issueDate) {
        this.issueDate = issueDate;
    }

    public boolean isApproved() {
        return isApproved;
    }

    public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
        isApproved = approved;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getBlockchainTx() {
        return blockchainTx;
    }

    public void setBlockchainTx(String blockchainTx) {
        this.blockchainTx = blockchainTx;
    }

    public String getUUID() {
        return UUID;
    }

    public void setUUID(String UUID) {
        this.UUID = UUID;
    }

    public boolean isMiningStatus() {
        return miningStatus;
    }

    public void setMiningStatus(boolean miningStatus) {
        this.miningStatus = miningStatus;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreateDateTime() {
        return createDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateDateTime(LocalDateTime createDateTime) {
        this.createDateTime = createDateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdateDateTime() {
        return updateDateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateDateTime(LocalDateTime updateDateTime) {
        this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
    }

    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Item> getInvoiceItems() {
        return invoiceItems;
    }

    public void setInvoiceItems(List<Item> invoiceItems) {
        this.invoiceItems = invoiceItems;
    }


}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "invoice_item_id")
    long id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    Product product;
    int quantity;
    double price;
    String currency;
    @OneToOne
    Invoice invoice;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createDateTime;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;

    public Item() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Invoice getInvoice() {
        return invoice;
    }

    public void setInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
        this.invoice = invoice;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreateDateTime() {
        return createDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreateDateTime(LocalDateTime createDateTime) {
        this.createDateTime = createDateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdateDateTime() {
        return updateDateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateDateTime(LocalDateTime updateDateTime) {
        this.updateDateTime = updateDateTime;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Product {  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    long id;
    String SKU;
    String productName;
    String description;
    String currency;
    double price;
    String unit;    
    int stock;
    int tax;
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Users user;

    public Product() {
        super();
    }
    public Product(String productName, String description, String currency, double price, String unit, int stock, String SKU, int tax) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.description = description;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.price = price;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.SKU = SKU;
        this.tax = tax;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }
    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getSKU() {
        return SKU;
    }

    public void setSKU(String SKU) {
        this.SKU = SKU;
    }

    public int getTax() {
        return tax;
    }

    public void setTax(int tax) {
        this.tax = tax;
    }
}
```

And the user

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @JsonAlias("last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createDateTime;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;
    public Users() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }


}
```

While I am calling

```
Optional<Invoice> invoice = invoiceRepository.findById(id);
```

I am getting

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException' exception.
```

In the invoice items array in Invoice entity. But insertion works fine.

Also it is doing some strange behavior when I first wrote it it was working fine and I am clueless what I have changed its completely not working.

I suspect it is a problem with lazy loading and I tried calling size on the array list too but no luck.

Please help me.

Comment: Please add invoiceRepository class code in the question

Comment: Here it is: public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {
}

Comment: Did you mark this  interface  @Repository

Comment: Yes I did. I make all the repo with @Repository

Comment: Your calling method of  invoiceRepository.findById(id); should have @Transactional

Comment: You mean to say I should define this method signature in interface with @transnational ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187510/discussion-between-govind-parashar-and-dave-b).

Answer (score 0):

Check below steps:

1. Your Repository Interface marked `@Repository`
2. Your service class marked `@Service`
3. Your calling method to get records inside your service class marked
   `@Transactional` (`@Transactional` Spring annotation to be set on the
   method or no class level)
4. May you got exception `Packet for query is too large`
5. SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet